# Ubuntu - Video Recording Software

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am working on Ubuntu platform and i want to record video of my application, is there any video recording software for the ubuntu platform? i think snagit is there but it is not for ubuntu.

Please suggest me name and suggestions !!

Thanx

Comment: check the `ubuntu software centre` saw a few apps there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give RecordMyDesktop a shot. Should work fine.

Comment: ya i done with the same software, thanx for the quick support

Comment: @Paresh thats what we're here for :) good to know that i could help.

Comment: thanx !! I am also doing the same job on SO as you are doing here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/pm-paresh-mayani